# I can't run uniswap-interface using npm and yarn from github

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, types, sass

I have cloned the project from a Github repo.
But I can't run the project correctly on my local.
Please help me.

Comment: Can you please try to npm install again?

Comment: I have tried but it is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see this code in your package.json file.

```
./node_modules/@uniswap/?(v3-core|v3-periphery)/artifacts/contracts/**/*.json
```

Please change to this.

```
./node_modules/@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/**/*.json
```

Comment: But I have an issue too

Comment: What's that? can you please post it as another issue?